# Python hangs for too long on with open

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing JavaScript source files in python 3.5. A loop checks out all commits from a github repository, and the script loops through all changed files. When a file is changed in two subsequent checkouts (which means, it changed in the commit), the script can hang on the with(open...) line for seconds, even for moderate (~5-8 MB) file sizes. I have created an example script, that imitates the problem:

```
test_data = "./sample.js"
for _ in range(10):
    start1 = time.time()
    with open(file=test_data, mode="rb", buffering=1) as f:
        end1 = time.time()
        start2 = time.time()
        line_content = f.readlines()
        ## Do some processing
    end2 = time.time()
    print("Processing file {} is done.".format(test_data))
    print("Time spent on open is {0:10f}.".format(end1 - start1))
    print("Time reading is {0:10f}.".format(end2 - start2))
    with open(test_data, mode="a", encoding="utf-8") as fw:
        fw.write("test")
```

The sample.js file is around 7 MB. Here is the output:

```
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   0.000000.
Time reading is   0.017001.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.683999.
Time reading is   0.013999.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.651003.
Time reading is   0.012030.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.638999.
Time reading is   0.014997.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   2.282346.
Time reading is   0.013001.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.701004.
Time reading is   0.011998.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.689004.
Time reading is   0.012995.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.707036.
Time reading is   0.012959.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.701031.
Time reading is   0.012969.
Processing file ./sample.js is done.
Time spent on open is   1.653999.
Time reading is   0.019003.
```

I have tried to use Process from multiprocessing, calling the garbage collector and also ExitStack from contextlib, but nothing helped.

Any ide what could cause this behaviour?

EDIT: Seems like the problem is Windows specific (at least, it wasn't as significant on Linux and MacOS).

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with `buffering=1`. [Check the docs for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) to see if you really mean this parameter to equal 1.

Comment: No, it's the same for all ```bufering``` sizes.

Comment: Are the files located locally? Or on a network drive?

Comment: All the files are local.

Comment: could you try with an `try open finally close` rather than the `with` context ?  i wonder if the times are not somehow misattributed.  unlikely, but...

Comment: And what are the results if you are reading line by line?

Comment: FWIW, NTFS is notoriously slow when dealing with many small files (though I wouldn't expect it to be *this* slow.)

Comment: In the meantime it turned out, that it has to do with the OS (Windows to be precise). So yeah, NTFS and Windows together are probably the causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS is the culprit!!

This is why in the `multiprocessing` documentation they added a specific paragraph for Windows in the [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods). I highly recommend to read the Programming Guidelines as they already include all the required information to write portable multi-processing code.

Comment: The problem persists without multiprocessing, but yeah, the main cause is the Windows. Thanks for the suggestion though, I will definitely check it.